# Ajax search bar isn't working with Laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8, searchbar

I'm trying to add a search bar for my suppliers using ajax in my Laravel project, I had trouble with it using it in the products search bar in my front office so I tried to follow the same steps in my back office but it doesn't seem to work, no error is showing so I don't know what's wrong please help me
here is my script

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    fetch_customer_data();
    function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('fournisseurSearch') }}",
            method:'GET',
            data: {query: query},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#result').html(data.html);
                } else {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            }
        })
    }
    $(document).on('keyup', '#keyword', function($e){ // define event parameter
            var query = $(this).val();

            fetch_customer_data(query);
            $e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

here is my input

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Cherchez ici..." class="form-control" id="keyword" name="keyword" >
```

and here is my controller

```
try{
        if($request->ajax()) {
            $query = $request->get('query');
            if(empty($query)) {
                return back()->withError('Aucun resultat trouvée');
             }
            else {
                $f = Fournisseur::where('nomSociete','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                            ->orWhere('activite','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                            ->orWhere('adresse','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                            ->get();

            }
            $total = $f->count();
            $html = view('back.fournisseurs.search_result', [
                    'fournisseurs' => $f,
                ])->render();


            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'html' => $html,
                'total' => $total,
            ], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => "Something went wrong!",
            ], 403);
        }
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
        Alert::error('Erreur ', $e->getMessage())->autoClose(false);
        return redirect()->back();
    }catch (Error $e) {
        // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
        Alert::error('Erreur ', $e->getMessage())->autoClose(false);
        return redirect()->back();
    }




and my route 
route::get('fournisseurs/search','FournisseurController@search')->name('fournisseurSearch');
```

**Edit**
here is what my tab shows
[image: result]

[image: error]

Comment: What is the response/output you are getting from your ajax request. Are you getting the intended response? Can you post what the response is for the ajax request from your network tab on your browser?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Is this a JS problem (where the browser does not build the request properly), or a PHP problem (where the server does not handle the request properly)?

Comment: i don't know what's wrong it doesn't show any error

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i checked that my jquery is imported and my code worked for me n a previous example so I don't know whether  it's a js problem or  PHP problem I posted a picture of my console while typing a product's name

Comment: Then please check whether this is a JS problem or a PHP problem. An open network console is already the first step, take the next one: inspect the request that is sent, and check whether it looks as expected. Then check whether PHP handles the request properly (do this by either using vardump or a proper debugger). Then check whether the response is sent as expected

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is when I type a product's name it is supposed to return for me the table lines of my search  result but nothing is showing not even an error except in my network it is showing status 302 don't know what it means

Comment: What have you tried to check that further? 302 is a redirect. What does that response contain?

Comment: @NicoHaase it says failed to load response data, and I don't know what to do to check anything else because I'm new to ajax, and by the way, I tried to var dump the DB result in my controller but it's not showing so I guess its JS problem?

Comment: @Abishek it is not showing me any error expect 'Failed to load response data'

Comment: Who is "it"? And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Maybe the redirect happens within your own code?

Comment: @NicoHaase by it i mean  the response  in my network tab check out the picture i just edited

Comment: Have you checked your Laravel log file? Any details there on what is causing error 302? And any reason why you are not returning the error on the catch blocks? With an ajax request, `redirect()->back()` will have not effect. Try to log the error or return the error on the catch block. Possible there is an error and the catch blocks are executed

Comment: @Abishek i am  using the try catch block :  }catch (Exception $e) {
            // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            Alert::error('Erreur ', $e->getMessage())->autoClose(false);
            return redirect()->back();
        }catch (Error $e) {
            // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            Alert::error('Erreur ', $e->getMessage())->autoClose(false);
            return redirect()->back();
        }

Comment: anything on the error logs? and can you return the error message instead of `return redirect()->back()` to see if the response returns any error message?